# Designing a Modulator for a digital communication signal

Tags: digital-communications

If I have a device and its hardware that is a low-power and that the instantaneous energy it uses must be constant and my specifications indicate that the modulator must be rate adaptive. what modulation technique should I use, PAM modulation, QAM modulation, Phase modulation or multi-dimensional modulation?

I think my question here is what's the relation of PAM, QAM, Phase modulation and multi-dimensional modulation with rate, power and energy.

Comment: Break up into 3 questions please.

Comment: Edited it to only 1 question. Thank you for alerting. I am new here

Comment: Needs way more detail.  Describe what this is actually going to be used for.  A lot of schemes from crude FSK all the way up to something fancy like LoRa would have roughly the same power even as their (effective) data rate and reliability is dialed up and down.

Comment: I believe that after I read my question many times is, I think what I want to understand is like the difference or an explanation for all four mentioned Modulations (PAM, QAM, PM and Multi-dimensional Modulation)  relationship with Power, Energy (or instantaneous energy) and rate adaptability.

Comment: A desire for an introductory explanation of the function and differences of various modulations is a need to consult traditional reference materials.  It is not a place for stack exchange sites, which are rather intended only for *highly specific* questions which remain *after* consulting reference materials.

Comment: Any device dealing with the manipulation of voltages and currents will not have a constant value of instantaneous energy.